# Measuring JavaScript performance

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a JavaScript file that takes an input, does some calculations with it, and returns a result. Now, I'd like to measure its performance, checking for example how much does it take to run 1.000 inputs. The problem is that I have nearly no knowledge of Javascript (the code isn't mine, neither), so I don't have any idea of how to do this. StackOverflowing I found some similar questions, but it's about "how much does it take for the script to run once" rather than "how much does it take for the script to elaborate 1.000 inputs".

If it can help, [this](http://www.nayuki.io/res/chemical-equation-balancer-javascript.js) is the script.

Comment: Try using [**jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/). It will let you include whatever scripts you need, and set up a test case, then you can see how the performance is, and compare against other variations of the same code etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this (depending on if the window console exists and has the time property):

```
if('console' in window && 'time' in window.console){

    console.time('time');
    for (var k=0;k<1000;k++) {
        derp(input);
    }
    console.timeEnd('time');

} else {

    var d = new Date();
    for (var k=0;k<1000;k++) {
        derp(input);
    }
    console.log('result: ' + new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() + 'ms');

}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I needed (checks for runtime of a single run), but can be easily fixed. Going to edit to match the request.

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello and what would you like to do? Measure each run individually? In that case, put the code inside the loop.

Comment: I didn't notice the for loop was implicit, so added it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to measure and analyze this script, you just need to grow your javascript knowledge (at least a little bit).

then you could use a benchmarking tool like [benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/). you can use it in your browser or within node.js.

jsperf.com uses benchmark.js. you could set up a testcase there which should be done within minutes. it is usually designed to compare 2 scripts, but you could just put your script into both tests and you have a first indication