# I need tool to find usage and unused javascript file in my project

Tags: performance, javascript

I my project i am using few third party javascript library.But few are very huge in size.So I want to find out the usage of each javascript file in my application (in other words , where and all I used this js file in my application).

If any one suggest this tool will be help full.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/) to measure JavaScript performance. The site will allow you to run benchmarks if you upload the code.

Microsoft also has a tool for Visual Studio 2008 known as [Microsoft Visual Studio AJAX Profiling Extensions](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/AjaxView) which can measure the performance of portions of web applications, including JavaScript.

If you're using Internet Explorer, you can also use the [MS Performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/28/measuring-web-page-performance.aspx) JavaScript Object.

A similar thread was also asked here: [Measuring JavaScript performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789635/measuring-javascript-performance)

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for reply.I am using backbone.js (its a javascript framework ) as a client side and java/j2ee as server side.

"JSPerf" - I hope its for code coverage you can write test cases like SONAR .

My Expectation is some tool/add-on/plugin can find usage  of all javascript library in my project in the form of graphical or data representation.

usage in the sense , Not a performance . That how many places I have used this library.Assume I have used "datepicker.js", So I want know , In how many places I have used this datapicker component?
Thanks again And sorry for the communication gap.